# How to print the least used vowel in a string?

Tags: python, counter, sentence

I want the user to be able to enter a piece of string (I know how to do this)

Then I want Python to count how many times each vowel (aeiou) is used.

After counting how many times each vowel is used, I need the program to return the least used vowel/s which is/are used at least once. If a vowel is not used it should not be returned. In the event of a tie for least used both should be returned.

If no vowels are used, it should print an error code "No vowels were used" (I know how to do this)

For example: If this is how many times the vowels were used in a sentence:

```
a=4
b=2
c=0
d=0
e=2
```

It should print "The least USED vowels were b and c, with 2 uses".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Remove all non-vowels chars from the string.
2. Split the string by chars.
3. use the `Counter` on the list you got from #2.

---

```
import re
from collections import Counter
s = 'asdfwerasdfwaxciduso'
only_vowels = re.sub(r"[^aeiou]", "", s)
c = Counter(list(only_vowels))
c.most_common()[-1]
```

Comment: This is actually really helpful...Thank-you. The only thing this coding doesn't let me do is the following: If the least used vowel is used the same number of times as another vowel, then both vowels must be printed. How can I do this?

Comment: I can't find your response to my comment? How to print both vowels if there is more than one least common vowel? Other than this - perfect answer. I will mark as accepted answer soon - will give you chance to respond as I still am unsure how to print multiple least common vowels!

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Now I see the complete comment. Did you check the value of `c.most_common()`? You can loop over it (in reverse order) and stop when you need :)

Comment: Awesome, think I've finally got there. Thank-you Dekel.

Comment: You don't need to convert the string to a list before passing it to Counter(): Counter() accepts strings as well (actually all iterables, and also mappings).

Answer (score 0):

Do it the hard way - letter by letter. Iterate over the string with a for loop and for each letter increment a dictionary value. At the end, check the keys with vowels and find the smallest.

Comment: Thanks - How can I go about ignoring any vowels which were used zero times?

Comment: If a letter isn't used, it doesn't have a key. Use a defaultdict from Collections with a default value of 1 so it won't freak out trying to add one the first time.

Comment: Thanks - last Q - assume two vowels share the same, lowest value. How can I get it to print both of them?

Comment: Hmmm... find min(d.values()) then do a count of that value to see if there is a tie?

Comment: @zenlc2000, Much better to use the tools the language gives you. Check my answer.

Comment: Yeah. I thought I had a pretty good answer until the tie question. Regex is a weak point for me so anything else is an easier answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to sort the letters based on their values and remove the consonants and print the first vowel.